# Any performance difference between using variables or constants in Entity Framework query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I noticed that if I specify a constant in an EF query that the value gets inlined, but if I specify that same value as a variable then EF creates a subquery for it and passes it in as a parameter. Are there any performance differences between the two approaches?

I have some massive Linq queries and I'm wondering if using constants might help with performance in terms of both the query execution (and plan caching) and in the translation from Linq to SQL.

Comment: Constants are replaced with their values on compile time, while variables are calculated at run time. This is the reason why EF can get the value of a constant inlined but can't do the same for a variable. There probably are performance differences, but it's impossible to estimate them from the data you have provided in your question. [Rase your horses.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: The best way to measure this is to benchmark both ways and record the results over a large number of tests.  Keep in mind that any kind of benchmark using the network or remote servers is going to give different results depending on your setup and load of those resources.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I'm interested in whether an inlined constant will result in the execution plan being cached and reused and whether the translation to SQL is faster. As far as I can tell, these questions would not be query-specific, but would apply to all queries. What additional info could I provide to help in answering these?

Comment: I don't know, but it's possible to test, I guess. You could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check out this article from TechNet:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175580(v=sql.105).aspx

It states that if you use literals, then the query optimizer should recognize it, but sometimes it might not.

> The only difference between the execution plans for these queries is
>   the value stored for the comparison against the ProductSubcategoryID
>   column. While the goal is for SQL Server to always recognize that the
>   statements generate essentially the same plan and reuse the plans, SQL
>   Server sometimes does not detect this in complex SQL statements.

Note the words "complex" and "sometimes" — quite a concrete explanation, isn't it? :)

The article also goes on to explain that if you use parameters, it "helps" the engine to reuse plans (again, concrete), some things about simple parameterization and forced parameterization.

So the documentation says that it is not certain, but usually this should not make a difference. As or my own experience: I've found that the engine is able to recognize the constants in queries generated by EF quite well. I had the same question a while back, and did some checking on Azure SQL. I wouldn't say I examined the most complex generated SQL queries of the world, but they were not just simple select-where-let-join combos.

But again, that was for my queries in a specific version of the engine. To be sure, I would suggest you also check your queries in question, and then you can be sure.